# constructor with one, default argument

Tags: c++, constructor, default-value, default-constructor

i searched but could not find the answer.

So I have my c++ constructor:

```
MyClass(string username = "something");
```

note this is the only constructor I have.

in my main, I do:

```
MyClass one();
MyClass two = MyClass();
```

are these two expressions equivalent? is the compiler gonna call my constructor with the default string, or is it gonna call the default (empty) constructor?

What would change if I did have a constructor MyClass(); ? I guess that would not compile, right?

Comment: `MyClass one();` [Refferred to as the most Vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work) Its not actually a declaration of the variable one. But a forward declaration of a function called one.

Answer (score 4):

`MyClass one();`

This declares a function `one` returning a `MyClass` object and taking no arguments.

If you have both default constructor (of the form `MyClass()`) and default argument constuctor (of the form `MyClass(string s = "string")` ) which one would be called if you don't pass any argument?

For example this would not compile

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
   MyClass(std::string username = "something") {}
   MyClass(){}
};

int main()
{
   MyClass one();
   MyClass two = MyClass(); //ambiguous call here
}
```

Comment: Also, `two = MyClass()` will not compile because the type is missing.

Comment: @Jon : I am assuming that he somehow missed the type.

Comment: Unless it is previously declared in that function, or defined in the class.  By itself, you're right.

Comment: @Prasoon: I know -- it's just for the sake of completeness of the answer.

Comment: "You can't have both default constructor and default argument constructor defined within a class." this is incorrect. and it's sort of fractally incorrect: both constructors in the OP's example are default constructors, and yes you can have two or more of them. it makes it practically impossible to call the one that doesn't have formal arguments, but it's OK to have it there. Please correct.

Comment: @Alf : My mistake. Corrected!!

Comment: @Martin : Where did I mention that it declares a variable?

Comment: There are thousands of folks around on SO. Why do you think it's @Martin who downvoted you?

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb : That was a wild guess. :P

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: Not me. But it was late last night. Removed comments. But the explanation could be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyClass one;
MyClass two = MyClass();
```

If this is what was meant then `one` and `two` will call the same constructor, which happens to be your constructor, which happens to be the only constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It will call your constructor.  If you define a constructor yourself--*any* constructor regardless of the number of arguments--the compiler will not generate a default constructor.

[edit] As Prasoon Saurav says, `MyClass one();` declares a function.  You want `MyClass one;`, note: no parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions will have the same nett effect, but the aren't strictly equivalent. The first calls your constructor on `one`. The second constructs a temporary and then assigns it to `two`, thus invoking the class's copy-constructor.

Comment: While the copy-constructor call can be optimized away, it still has to be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

> are these two expressions equivalent?

They are not equivalent.

> MyClass one();

it is function one(), return MyClass.

if you want to declare object of MyClass, It should be:

> MyClass one;

or

> MyClass one = MyClass();

for question:

> is the compiler gonna call my constructor with the default string, or
>   is it gonna call the default (empty) constructor?

if you declare your own constructor, compiler will never generate default constructor, then there is no default constructor now. for example:

```
MyClass(string username); // declare constructor take 1 parameter
MyClass three; // error, no matching constructor
```